# Laravel "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" error when trying to render markdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, markdown

I'm trying to show some changelog content on my Laravel page with this markdown plugin, but it always throws this error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

```
@markdown($changelog->content)
```

The content is not null, all the content is there and it gets created and stored properly.

I found out about @isset but no matter how I use it, it still shows that error.

```
@isset($changelog->content)
  @markdown($changelog->content)
@endisset
```

Note: I'm using Laravel 5.8, this is an older project.

Comment: Your php version is?

Comment: It's PHP 7.4.30